# Best alternative for data fixes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

When a rails project grows a lot, you can find yourself having trouble with fixes for the data in the production database.

I have normally used migrations or specific rake tasks for this, but I was wondering if a system similar to migrations existed for keeping the database fixes and run them when needed.

Comment: What sort of *data fixes* are you talking about, here...?

Comment: If you loaded something with seeds or from a legacy database that needs fixing (wrong country codes, or the tax of a country has changed, or a new validation is entered and you have to fix previous data that is not right..)

Comment: In that case, you may want to do those type of data fixes *outside* of Rails, first... and then update the database in some other way to reflect those data fixes.  This sounds like more of a general "data cleaning" issue to me than a Rails-related issue. :)

Comment: I would like to know if there is some system/gem ala migrations to deal with data changes in the database, rather than data structure. If not, I should start researching to create one, because it's needed in big projects ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you probably figured this out by now but there IS a gem for this... it is called datafix

https://github.com/Casecommons/datafix

basically you create a datafix, like a migration, and a spec for it, then you can run it as needed on the server.

Comment: Thanks. I have the basic structure for a gem done but I don't have the time right now to flesh it out. I'll check this one.

Comment: Link seems to be broken now.

Comment: @MichaelHagar https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pivotal-network-datafix

Comment: Is something out there for datafixes still living in 2020?

Answer (score 2):

The following gems can be also used for this purpose:

- [nondestructive_migrations](https://github.com/jasonfb/nondestructive_migrations)
- [datafix](https://github.com/Casecommons/datafix)
- [migrake](https://github.com/foca/migrake)
- [migration-data](https://github.com/ka8725/migration_data)
- [data-migrate](https://github.com/ajvargo/data-migrate)

I prefer `nondestructive_migrations` and `datafix` they are very similar - nondestructive_migrations simpler implementation building on rails migrations.